# Is sid string a well-known sid

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a fast way (without copying all well-known sids into the code) to determine if a sid string is a well-known one?

```
bool IsWellKnownSid(string sid)
```

Comment: @David, was that rhetorical for a better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WellKnownSidType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype) enum, like Austin mentioned, but you'll still have to loop through each value to check if it matches.

Here is a method that would do that:

```
private static WellKnownSidType[] _wellKnownSids = (WellKnownSidType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(WellKnownSidType));

public bool IsWellKnownSid(SecurityIdentifier sid) {
    foreach (var wellKnown in _wellKnownSids) {
        if (sid.IsWellKnown(wellKnown)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `_wellKnownSids` field is to prevent you from calling `Enum.GetValues` every single time you call the method when the values will always be the same.

You can change that into an extension method if you prefer:

```
public static bool IsWellKnownSid(this SecurityIdentifier sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you could use Microsot's ENUM:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

A quick and dirty approach that seems to work at a basic level without much real testing:

```
var account = System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.AccountCertAdminsSid;
var reference = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-0-0"); 
Console.WriteLine(reference.IsWellKnown(account));
```